# Hyperlink doesn't activates macro in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to get a hyperlink to activate a macro. I can't use a fixed target address, because I've several links; The goal is to create a clickable history of taken step. So I need to create a back button.

I already tried this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$4" Then 
       MsgBox "This isn't what I had in mind"
    Else
       MsgBox "MACRO!"

        Exit Sub
    End If 

End Sub
```

Anybody an idea?

If I click the hyperlink it only show the code for that cell.
The code is in the Worksheet module.

**The general idea:**

I'm making a workbook that calculates based on several steps (40 in total). For example: if sum is larger than 9 go to step 4, if not, go to step 21.

But because we're all human and mistakes can be made, i want excel to make a list of all the steps that have been taken and their answer. I want to make the steps in this list clickable, so when they click on the step, the can go back to that step and continue from there. So a lot of hyperlinks :)

Comment: What do you mean by clickable history? What should go in there? Every hyperlink selected, or every cell selected, or every cell changed...? Every time they changed a value? Do you mean something like the 'undo' list (which erases itself when you launch a macro)

Comment: Where did you put that code? Should be in the worksheet code module.  Try adding `Debug.Print Target.Range.Address` and make sure it's giving you what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Macro doesn't work if you use  =HYPERLINK(), you have to convert it via 'rightclick', Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Worksheet_SelectionChange with the same setup?

Comment: I have several links listing horizontally. I think that if I use the Worksheet_SelectionChange I'll have to declare every possible line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, I've copy and pasted your code into the "Sheet1" module of a new Excel workbook, and put a hyperlink on the 'Sheet1' tab to click on. The MsgBox pops up as expected.

I believe the macro will only work if the code is in the Sheet module for the Worksheet that the users is clicking the link on.

Comment: I tried both. If I click or double click the link, it only shows the formula. 
`=IF(B16<1;"";HYPERLINK(""; "BACK"))`

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work for the hyperlink function. Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a Hyperlink Back button, you can always add one to the Quick Access Toolbar:

[image]

Comment: because I have to generate several back buttons

Comment: @Nathalii.  one for each destination or one for each sheet??

Comment: For each destination.